# Is there any method or way in C# to add items in a List<T> on a LIFO basis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, stack

this is an easy one. I have a `List<T>` in C# and I woudl like to add some elements on a LIFO basis, so on the "bottom" of the `List<T>`. 
For several reasons I cannot use the **Stack** class.

Thanks

Francesco

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: `LinkedList<T>` doesn't implement `IList<T>` (because it has no indexed access)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Items added to a `List<T>` using the `Add` method are placed at the end of the list. If you want to process the list so that it's LIFO, either iterate in reverse (meaning you change the way you *process* the list) or always use `Insert(0, item)` to add elements to the list (meaning you change the way you *populate* the list).

Comment: True on inserting at front, though that does make the insert O(n) instead of O(1)-ish.

Comment: @James: Right; it's definitely not the method I'd choose (I'm curious why the OP can use `Stack<T>`), but if he wants to be able to iterate the list in this fashion and can't control how it's iterated, then I'm not seeing much of a choice apart from using a temporary list.

Comment: +1 for processing in reverse.  That's a better answer, although I'm still curious why he isn't using a stack...

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Also here my question turned into a debate on computational speed. Nice. So the scenario is that I have a already populated List<T> and I want to add some elements in the tail. Does your method stills hold in this scenario? Thanks

Comment: @Francesco: Calling `Add` on a list (which adds the item to the end of the list) is an O(1) operation. As long as you're able to iterate the list in reverse (`list[list.Count - 1]` to `list[0]`), then that's the fastest way of using the `List<T>` in LIFO mode.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: in my application the performance is not a relevant quality requirement so I can afford some costly operation without any problem. And moreover, I cannot do otherwise...

Comment: @Francesco: I don't understand what you're asking. Calling `Add will put the item at the end of the list, and calling `Insert(0,...)‘ will put it at the end. Use whichever is more convenient for you. Is there another question?

Answer (score 7):

Yes the `Add()` method adds to the end of the list, you can use `RemoveAt(yourList.Count - 1)` to remove last, and `yourList[yourList.Count - 1]` to peek at the last.

Though I'm curious, why can't you use the Stack() class?

Comment: In this way you stay at O(1) time instead of O(n) pushing at front

Comment: yourList[yourList.Count-1], unless it's VB and VB is still using 1 based arrays...

Comment: @James: Inserts to the beginning of a List<T> are O(n)?  Are you just assuming how its implemented, or do you have source code or benchmarks?

Comment: @clintp I haven't looked at the source, but you can specify an initial capacity when instantiating a list, so it is likely based on an array in the background, not a linked list.

Comment: @Kendrick it's flagged as C#, so why muddy the waters with the evil that is VB ;)

Comment: @clintp: It's easy to see what `List<T>` does in Reflector (or just ILDasm if you're good with IL). `List<T>` uses  an array under the covers and will create a new array when the size of the list is going to exceed the size of the array. Since it's an array, an insertion means that all existing values that are at or beyond the insertion index must be copied one-by-one. This is O(n)

Comment: @Kendrick: I'm just *really* wary of blanket statements that assume implementation details like that ("likely that..").  James tells his friends, they tell their friends, and soon it's "everyone knows that..."  There are other array-like structures that might be optimized using an initial capacity that don't have to be re-allocated and moved for a front-insert.

Comment: @Adam: See, that's useful.  :)

Comment: Arrays in VB.NET are 0 based. However, they are created as though they are 1 based. For example: `Dim strings(5) As String` creates an array with **6** values. `strings(0)` to `strings(5)` are all valid. `List`s act the same in VB.NET as they do in C#.

Comment: @James Michael Hare: It looks like my question turn into a debate on computational speed. Anyway I cannot use the **Stack** class because I create the 'List<T>' from a LINQ query at first and then I want to Add some elements in a LIFO basis. I cannot insert the elements to the List<T> before adding the "LIFO ones" because I need those values to make a comparison and decide which "LIFO" elements I need to add. So the scenario is that I have a already populated List<T> and I want to add some elements in the tail. Does your answer cover such case? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can insert anywhere in the list you'd like.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert(0,T)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx

This isn't a stack though.  If you want to remove objects again as you use them, I'd consider extending a stack...

Answer (score 1):

LIFO and FIFO is **not a question of adding** but a question of **removing**.

You can use `List<T>` and always pick up the last item:

```
List<int> list = Enumerable.Range(1,100).ToList();
While(list.Count>0)
{
    list.RemoveAt(list.Count-1);
}
```

Comment: True, and if I had to use a `List<T>` as a stack then this is how I'd do it, but I suspect that if there are constraints that prevent him from using a `Stack<T>`, then those same constraints probably mean that he has to populate the list in reverse so that it emulates LIFO when iterated in order.

Comment: I know that LIFO/FIFO are removing policies but they work properly if you add the elements in a LIFO/FIFO basis. If you use LIFO to get the elements from a List<T> and the element you expect to "pop" from the List<T> instead of being in the tail is in the head, your algorythm won't work. Maybe a more proper way to formulate the question might be "How to add elements on the tail of a LIST<T>"